# Psycopg2: how to insert and update on conflict using psycopg2 with python?

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I am using psycopg2 to insert command to postgres database and when there is a confilict i just want to update the other column values.

Here is the query:

```
        insert_sql = '''
        INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, col3,col4)
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) (val1,val2,val3,val4)
        ON CONFLICT (col1)
        DO UPDATE SET
        (col2, col3, col4)
        = (val2, val3, val4) ; '''

        cur.excecute(insert_sql)
```

I want to find where I am doing wrong? I am using variables val1 , val2, val3 not actual values.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To quote from psycopg2's [documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html):

*Warning Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.*

Now, for an upsert operation you can do this:

```
insert_sql = '''
    INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, col3, col4)
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)
    ON CONFLICT (col1) DO UPDATE SET
    (col2, col3, col4) = (EXCLUDED.col2, EXCLUDED.col3, EXCLUDED.col4);
'''
cur.execute(insert_sql, (val1, val2, val3, val4))
```

Notice that the **parameters** for the query are being passed as a tuple to the `execute` statement (this assures psycopg2 will take care of adapting them to SQL while shielding you from injection attacks).

The `EXCLUDED` bit allows you to reuse the values without the need to specify them twice in the data parameter.

Comment: Very helpful! Small note - it should be 
(col2, col3, col4) = (EXCLUDED.col2, EXCLUDED.col3, EXCLUDED.col4);

Answer (score 7):

Using:

```
INSERT INTO members (member_id, customer_id, subscribed, customer_member_id, phone, cust_atts) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) ON CONFLICT (customer_member_id) DO UPDATE SET (phone) = (EXCLUDED.phone);
```

I received the following error:

```
psycopg2.errors.FeatureNotSupported: source for a multiple-column UPDATE item must be a sub-SELECT or ROW() expression
LINE 1: ...ICT (customer_member_id) DO UPDATE SET (phone) = (EXCLUDED.p...
```

Changing to:

```
INSERT INTO members (member_id, customer_id, subscribed, customer_member_id, phone, cust_atts) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) ON CONFLICT (customer_member_id) DO UPDATE SET (phone) = ROW(EXCLUDED.phone);
```

Solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, col3,col4)
        VALUES (val1,val2,val3,val4)
        ON CONFLICT (col1)
        DO UPDATE SET
        (col2, col3, col4)
        = (val2, val3, val4) ; '''
```

Comment: it is giving error column val1 doesnot exist, I dont know why it is treating val1 as column

Comment: You need to give  literals or constants like 10, 'abc' for val1, val2, etc If you want to use a variable you need to use a prepared statement : see https://www.psycopg.org/articles/2012/10/01/prepared-statements-psycopg/

Comment: i am using variable

Comment: In place of val1 , val2, i should give {},{} and them cur.exceute( insert_sql.format(val1,val2)) , is this correct.

Comment: can you please help ?

Comment: Sorry but I am not a python/psycopg2 specialist.  <br/> Try to adapt this code:  <br/>   `cur.execute('''
    PREPARE prepared_insert(text, text) AS
       INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2)
        VALUES ($1,$2')
''')
val1 = '{}'
val2 ='{}'
cur.execute('EXECUTE prepared_insert(%s, %s)', (val1, val2))`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anyone comment on this, but you can utilize `psycopg2.extras.execute_values` to insert/update many rows of data at once, which I think is the intended solution to many inserts/updates.

There's a few tutorials on YouTube that illustrate this, one being [How to connect to PSQL Database using psycopg2 + Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSSSaD0V9fI)

In the video they load a dataframe using `pandas` and insert the data from a CSV source into multiple schemas/tables. The code snippet example in that video is

```
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values


sql_insert = """    
    INSERT INTO {state}.weather_county(fips_code, county_name, temperature)
    VALUES %s
    ON CONFLICT (fips_code) DO UPDATE
    SET
        temperature=excluded.temperature,
        updated_at=NOW()
    ;
    """



grouped = new_weather_data.groupby(by='state') ## new_weather_data is a dataframe

conn = create_rw_conn(secrets=secrets)


for state, df in grouped:
    # select only the neccessary columns
    df = df[['fips_code', 'county_name', 'temperature']]
    print("[{}] upsert...".format(state))
    # convert dataframe into list of lists for `execute_values`
    data = [tuple(x) for x in df.values.tolist()]
    cur = conn.cursor()
    execute_values(cur, sql_insert.format(state=state), data)
    conn.commit() # <- We MUST commit to reflect the inserted data
    print("[{}] changes were commited...".format(state))
    cur.close()
```

The Jupyter Notebook is [psycopg2-python-tutorial/new-schemas-tables-insert.ipynb](https://github.com/Johnnyboycurtis/psycopg2-python-tutorial/blob/main/new-schemas-tables-insert.ipynb)

Answer (score -5):

Here's the function that takes df, schemaname  of the table, name of the table, the column that you want to  use as a conflict in the name of conflict, and the engine created by create_engine of sqlalchemy. It updates the table with respect to conflict column. This is extended solution for the solution of @Ionut Ticus .
Don't use pandas.to_sql() together. pandas.to_sql() destroys the primary key setting. In this case, one need to set primary key by the ALTER query, which is a suggestion by the function below. Primary key does not necessarily be destroyed by pandas, one might haven't been set it. Error would be in that case:
there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table? Function will suggest you to execute below.

```
engine.execute('ALTER TABLE {schemaname}.{tablename} ADD PRIMARY KEY ({conflictcolumn});
```

Function:

```
def update_query(df,schemaname,tablename,conflictcolumn,engine ):
"""
This function takes dataframe as df, name of schema as schemaname,name of the table to append/add/insert as tablename, 
and column name that only  other elements of rows will be changed if it's existed as conflictname,
database engine as engine.
Example to engine : engine_portfolio_pg = create_engine('postgresql://pythonuser:vmqJRZ#dPW24d@145.239.121.143/cetrm_portfolio')
Example to schemaname,tablename : weatherofcities.sanfrancisco , schemaname = weatherofcities, tablename = sanfrancisco.

"""


excluded = ""
columns = df.columns.tolist()
deleteprimary = columns.copy()
deleteprimary.remove(conflictcolumn)
excluded = ""
replacestring = '%s,'*len(df.columns.tolist())
replacestring = replacestring[:-1]

for column in deleteprimary:
    excluded += "EXCLUDED.{}".format(column)+","
excluded = excluded[:-1]

columns = ','.join(columns)

deleteprimary  = ','.join(deleteprimary)

insert_sql = """ INSERT INTO {schemaname}.{tablename} ({allcolumns})
    VALUES ({replacestring})
    ON CONFLICT ({conflictcolumn}) DO UPDATE SET
    ({deleteprimary}) = ({excluded})""".format( tablename = tablename, schemaname=schemaname,allcolumns = columns, replacestring= replacestring,
                                               conflictcolumn= conflictcolumn,deleteprimary = deleteprimary,  excluded=excluded  )



conn = engine.raw_connection()
conn.autocommit = True

#conn = engine.connect()

cursor = conn.cursor()

i = 0
print("------------------------"*5)

print("If below error happens:")
print("there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table?")    
print("Primary key is not set,you can execute:")
print("engine.execute('ALTER TABLE {}.{} ADD PRIMARY KEY ({});')".format(schemaname,tablename,conflictcolumn))
print("------------------------"*5)
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    cursor.execute(insert_sql, tuple(row.values))
    conn.commit() 
    if i == 0:
        print("Order of Columns in Operated SQL Query for Rows")
        columns = df.columns.tolist()
        print(insert_sql%tuple(columns))
        print("----")
        print("Example of Operated SQL Query for Rows")
        print(insert_sql%tuple(row.values))
        print("---")
        
    i += 1 

conn.close()
```

Comment: Please DO NOT recommend this style of building dynamic SQL using Python string interpolation. See here [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) and here [Dynamic SQL](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) for reasons why.