# How to build a generic function in Python to Insert and update records?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, database, dbconnection

I wanted to build a generic function in Python to Insert a record into table `A` from table `B` if the record does not exists in table `A` else update with the data if the primary key is identified. I am not able to get the result with the below code:

```py
def insert_update_record(table_A, table_B):
    insert_query = "INSERT INTO {} SELECT * FROM {} WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM {} WHERE {}.id = {}.id)".format(table_A, table_B, table_A, table_B, table_A)
    update_query = "UPDATE {} SET {} = {} FROM {} WHERE {}.id = {}.id".format(table_A, table_A, table_B, table_A, table_B, table_A)
    
    cur.execute(insert_query)
    cur.execute(update_query)
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: what is the database you're using?

Comment: @Javad postgress

Comment: what error/results are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I should say `SELECT 1` in your `insert_query` is not ok and you probably need to change it to something like this:

```py
insert_query = "INSERT INTO {} SELECT * FROM {} WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM {} WHERE {}.id = {}.id) LIMIT 1".format(table_A, table_B, table_A, table_B, table_A)
```

But what you want to implement is a concept called **`Upsert`** in database concepts and I do it for you using `INSERT ON CONFLICT` statement like below:

```py
import psycopg2


def connect():
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(database ="name_of_your_database",
                            user = "user_of_this_database",
                            password = "password_forthis_user",
                            host = "localhost",
                            port = "5432")

        cur = conn.cursor()
    
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print ("Error while creating PostgreSQL table", error)
    
    return conn, cur

def insert_update_record(table_A, table_B):
    conn, cur = connect()
    upsert_query="""
INSERT INTO {}
SELECT * FROM {} LIMIT 1
ON CONFLICT (id) 
DO 
   UPDATE SET field_name = EXCLUDED.field_name || ';' || {}.field_name;
""".format(table_A, table_B, table_B)

    cur.execute(upsert_query)
    conn.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    insert_update_record("table_name_1", "table_name_2")
```

**Reference:**

To learn more about this concept in *Postgres* or other databases you can tour the below links:

[**Psycopg2: how to insert and update on conflict using psycopg2 with python?** <sup>[stackoverflow]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60845779/psycopg2-how-to-insert-and-update-on-conflict-using-psycopg2-with-python)

[**Insert, on duplicate update in PostgreSQL?** <sup>[stackoverflow]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql)

[**PostgreSQL Upsert Using INSERT ON CONFLICT statement** <sup>[POSTGRESQL TUTORIAL]</sup>](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-upsert/)

[**How to UPSERT (MERGE, INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE) in PostgreSQL?** <sup>[stackoverflow]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-to-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql)

[**Idiomatic way to implement UPSERT in PostgreSQL** <sup>[dba-stackexchange]</sup>](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13468/idiomatic-way-to-implement-upsert-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

Python uses `c.execute(q)` function to update a record from a table where `c` is cursor and `q` is the update query to be executed.

Syntax:

```py
# execute SQL query using execute() method.
cursor.execute(sql)
cursor.commit()
# get the record count updated
print(mycursor.rowcount, "record (s) affected")
```